# Rails Paperclip & Multiple File Uploads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, amazon-s3, paperclip

I am looking for a solution to give the user the ability to upload multiple images through one file_field. I have looked in to options such a Jquery File Upload and Uploadify but have yet to come across good examples with a working solution.

I already have multiple images setup,

```
 has_attached_file :asset,
                   :styles => { :large => "640x480", :medium => "300x300", :thumb => "100x100" },
                   :storage => :s3,
                   :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
                   :path => "/:contributor_id/:listing_name/:filename"
```

Right now I am displaying 5 individual file_fields

```
def new
  @listing = Listing.new
  5.times {@listing.assets.build }

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @listing }
  end
end
```

I would like to have

```
<%= f.file_field :asset, :multiple => true %>
```

That allows the user to select multiple files in their file browser. But how can I process these with a nested model? And get them to upload.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

So there are a few issues here.

First, Paperclip's `has_attached_file` method isn't an association to many files.  It looks like you're trying to build an "asset" as if it's a Rails association.  All Paperclip does is put a couple of fields into your table to store some meta-data about the file and you get one attached file per declaration of `has_attached_file`.  If you want to attach 5 files, you would need to do something like:

```
has_attached_file :asset1
has_attached_file :asset2
has_attached_file :asset3
has_attached_file :asset4
has_attached_file :asset5
```

OR, alternatively, you could create another model just to store the files.  For example:

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assets
end

class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :listing
  has_attached_file :picture
end
```

That way, you could have multiple assets attached to one listing (you didn't say what the original object was so I just called it "listing").

Second, there is no such thing as a multiple file upload in HTML (and, as such, the `file_field` method doesn't take a `:multiple => true` argument.  You'll have to use something beyond Rails built-in form handling if you want multiple-file upload.  Uploadify is a decent choice (that I've used before).  There is a gem that will transform file fields to use uploadify (and will support the `:multiple => true` syntax that you want): https://github.com/mateomurphy/uploadify_rails3/wiki.  However, I cannot vouch for how good it is.

My advice would be to start step-by-step.  Uploading via Flash to Rails can be a complicated process that involves dealing with the CSRF meta-tag and other fields in your form.  Start by making a form that allows a user to upload one file and stores it through Paperclip.  Then maybe break the `has_attached_file` declaration into another model so that you can have 1 or many files associated with a model (as shown in the multi-model code block above).  Then try adding Uploadify or another alternative.  Ernie Miller has a decent tutorial on integrating Uploadify: http://erniemiller.org/2010/07/09/uploadify-and-rails-3/.

To start, remember that `has_attached_file` can only attach *one* file.  When you try calling `@listing.assets` there is no "assets".  There is *an* asset.  You need to create a separate model yourself and use Rails' associations if you want multiple files.

Comment: I already do have another model created called "Listing". A listing has_many assets. I already can upload multiple assets, just not through a single "Choose File" field. if anyone has any good examples using uploadify that'd be great. I'm not sure how to do the background JS to process each image and POST them to the server properly.

Comment: You can add `:multiple => "multiple"` to your `file_field`, that enables multiple file selection from one html file input field (at least in Chrome). I haven't solved the problem of managing these uploads properly yet, but I know that post parameter includes an array of the multiple files you have picked and uploaded.

Comment: And you also have to add `:html => {:multipart => :true }` to your `form_for`.

Comment: Just to add to this: i would move the file uploading to ajax, allowing you to gather a list of files from the user and then upload them one at a time in the background:  this way it would appear to the user that they have uploaded lots of files at once, even though behind the scenes that's not what's happening.  You can also set any other params for how the resulting records might need to be organised on the server.  For file upload with ajax (jquery), which can be a bit tricky to get right, see eg http://abandon.ie/notebook/simple-file-uploads-using-jquery-ajax

Answer (score 8):

Accepted answer says there is no such thing as a multiple file upload in HTML.

```
<%= f.file_field :files, multiple: true %>
```

This allows you to select multiple images and send them as an array.

If you have the relationship `Dog has_many Images` and `Image has_attachment :file`, do this to get multiple images to upload at once:

In your html.erb

```
<%= form_for @dog, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field :files, accept: 'image/png,image/jpeg,image/gif', multiple: true %>
<%= end %>
```

In your controller

```
def dog_params
  params.require(:dog).permit files: []
end
```

In your Dog model

```
def files=(array = [])
  array.each do |f|
    images.create file: f
  end
end
```

This is assuming you're already able to upload one image but want to upgrade to multiple images at once. Notice that wait time will increase.

To help reduce wait time, peep my **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41866644/4812050)** on this question related to speed uploading.

Comment: I would upvote this so many times if I could. I was stuck for an entire day and found this first thing the next morning. GREAT way to start the day!!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a full example of multiple file uploads. Here a `user has_many uploads`.  Each `upload` model has an `avatar` which represents the file attachment.  Ultimately: we are creating many `uploads` when we create the `user`.

**The Models**

```
#models/user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :uploads

  def files=(array_of_files = [])
    array_of_files.each do |f|
      uploads.build(avatar: f, user: self)
    end
  end
end


#models/upload.rb
class Upload < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  has_attached_file :avatar
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => ["image/png"]
end
```

**The form:**

```
# views/users/_form.html.erb
<%= form_with(model: user, local: true) do |form| %>

  ...

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.file_field :files, multiple: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**The Controller**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show]

  def show
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    if @user.save
      redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.'
    end
  end

  private
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, files: [])
    end
end
```

**User#show**

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @user.name %>
</p>


<h3>Uploads</h3>
<div>
  <% @user.uploads.each do |upload|  %>
    <div>
      <%= link_to upload.avatar.url do%>
        <%= upload.avatar_file_name %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(@user) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', users_path %>
```