# Uploading and Resizing Multiple Images Using Mercury Editor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mercury-editor

I'm using the latest and greatest Mercury editor in my Rails 3.2.9 application.

I have adapted the Image model to allow uploading to s3:

```
  has_attached_file :image,
                    :styles => { :medium => "200x115" },
                    :storage => :s3,
                    :s3_protocol => 'https',
                    :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
                    :path => ":attachment/:id/:style/:filename",   
                    :url => ":attachment/:id/:style/:filename",           
                    :bucket => 'ps-wifi'
```

This is working fine.

I'm trying to figure out how I can allow the user to upload multiple images, each with different attributes.

For example, the above method works for a logo but we're need another, larger image at 600 x 350. Previously, I had another "has_attached_file" but am not sure how to achieve with Mercury.

Comment: This sounds more like a paperclip question than a mercury editor question, essentially for multiple image attachments without having you create multiple `has_attached_file` statements you'll have to create a new model for the exclusive purpose of handling upload attachments. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921537/rails-paperclip-multiple-file-uploads

Comment: Hey, I don't think the problem's with multiple uploads- it's more the way Mercury's dealing with them. It only seems to let you tag the images with "image". There's therefore no way I can see to differentiate between a 'logo' on the page and another placeholder. S