# Multiple upload with Paperclip in ror

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, paperclip, photos

I am using paperclip to upload one photo for one building. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KGmsaXhIdjc i have done it with this way.  But know I decide to upload many photos to one building.  Can I do that with paperclip or have to change it and use jQuery ? And if I can how ?  **Ps: if needed I will upload my code. ps: i am thinking to make 2 more columns in database for photo2 and photo 3**.. btw i have see all generates assets to do that. the think is that i have make it with different way to upload 1 photo. this means i have to change the all thing?

update 1:

in routes.rb

```
resources :buildings do 
      resources :photos
  end
```

in buldings>_form

```
<%= form_for(@building, :html=>{:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
  <% if @building.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@building.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this building from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @building.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :status %><br />
    <%= f.select :status, Building::STATUS, :prompt=>'Select status of the building' %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :description, :rows => 10 %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :price %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :price %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <!--<%= f.label :photo %><br />
    <%= f.file_field :photo %> -->
    <%= f.fields_for :photos do |photo| %>  
    <% if photo.object.new_record? %>
      <%= photo.file_field(:image) %>

     <% else %> 
        <%= image_tag(photo.url(:thumb)) %>
        <%= photo.hidden_field :_destroy %>
        <%= photo.link_to_remove "X"%>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

    <p><%= f.link_to_add "Add photo", :photos %></p>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

in model>building

```
 attr_accessible :description, :price, :status, :title, :photo

accepts_nested_attributes_for :photo, :allow_destroy => true

  has_attached_file :photo ,
                  :url  => "/assets/products/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                  :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/products/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
```

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/10922612/429758 & http://www.emersonlackey.com/article/rails-paperclip-multiple-file-uploads

Comment: i have try it and did't work. maybe I making something wrong i don't know.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can do it with paperclip. The way I do it is with nested resources and the [nested_form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) gem.

For example you `building has_many :photos` and `photo belongs_to :building`

Then in your `/views/buildings/_form.html.erb` you would write something like this:

```
<%= nested_form_for @building, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <%# all your building fields .... %>

  <%= f.fields_for :photos do |photo| %>  
    <% if photo.object.new_record? %>
      <%= photo.file_field(:image) %>
    <% else %> 
      <%= image_tag(photo.url(:thumb)) %>
      <%= photo.hidden_field :_destroy %>
      <%= photo.link_to_remove "X" %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

  <p><%= f.link_to_add "Add photo", :photos %></p>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

You will have to set `accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos, :allow_destroy => true` inside your `building.rb` model and make sure your `routes.rb` also include the nesting:

```
resources :buildings do 
  resources :photos
end
```

Comment: i have done evrything and says: 
ArgumentError in BuildingsController#new

No association found for name `photos'. Has it been defined yet?

Comment: some times it says me :  NoMethodError in BuildingsController#new

undefined method `key?' for nil:NilClass