# Add more than 1 photo to content in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I'm using Rails 4 and I'm trying to add more than 1 photo (up to 10 photos) to my content. For adding images i'm using paperclip and 1 photo upload works great for me.

```
class Place < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_attached_file :place_photo, :styles => { :small => "150x150>", :medium => "500x500>", :large => "1000x1000>"},
              :url  => "/assets/places/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
              :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/places/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"

  validates_attachment_presence :place_photo
  validates_attachment_size :place_photo, :less_than => 5.megabytes
  validates_attachment_content_type :place_photo, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png']

end
```

Of course i could make :place_photo2, :place_photo3... etc. ,but how can i make it better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new model, called for example `PlaceImage`. Configure the model with a one-to-many relationship with `Place` and you'll have that one `Place` can have infinite `PlaceImage`s.

Attach paperclip to the `PlaceImage` model instead of `Place`.

Comment: can you exlplain a bit more, please?

Comment: so. i shuold create new model, then add paperclip image to it (i need to make a table for it as i understand), and then how can i define more then 1 images in my form?

Comment: Yes, you create the new model and you can associate more than once model (image) to the original model. In order to allow multiple images in a single form, you can use nested attributes. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18535748/nested-paperclip-form-with-multiple-images

Comment: i jumped over 5 links and got this: http://www.emersonlackey.com/article/rails-paperclip-multiple-file-uploads I think that's it. i'll give it a try. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could set up a separate model (i.e. `Photographs`) and have the file attached to instances of that model. Then set up a `has_many :photographs` relationship.