# Multiple image upload rails 3.2.3 issue uninitialized constant Project::Asset

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, nested, paperclip

I'm using `paper-clip gem` to upload multiple images and I'm using `rails 3.2.3`.

I'm getting `an error uninitialized constant in controller's new method`.

I'm not able to understand what went wrong.

I have referred http://www.emersonlackey.com/article/rails-paperclip-multiple-file-uploads for using this gem.

Is there any specific links for multiple image uploads for `rails 3.2`?

Please help,

Thanks.

Comment: These two links might help you 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605787/uploading-multiple-files-with-paperclip 2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18535748/nested-paperclip-form-with-multiple-images