# Show.html.erb in nested_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

So sorry for the dumb question, but I can't solve my issue without help.. [Multiple upload with Paperclip in ror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14880100/multiple-upload-with-paperclip-in-ror?lq=1)
on this link I have everythig good. Everything works. But I have a problem how to write show.html.erb for my building model(actually I have poster). 
Here what I've tried in my app/views/poster/show.html.erb:

```
<% @poster.photos.each do |t| %>
<%= image_tag t.url(:medium) %>
<% end %>
```

but it doesn't show me any pictures.. Thanks

And I've tried this variant too:

```
<% for pic in @poster.photos %>
<%= image_tag pic.url(:medium) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What does `t.photo.url(:medium)` returns? A valid relative URL?

Comment: I'm rather new to RoR so I'm not sure, but I think yes. here is the place where I took this https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip

Comment: Take off the image_tag and just print `<%= t.photo.url(:medium) %>`, it will show you the relative Paths of the files. It should be something like /assets/images/medium/XXXX.jpg ; when you have this URL, try to check if there is a file a this location

Comment: There should not be photo. t.url(:medium). Misprint while writing the question.

Comment: Even when I change like you said, it doesn't show anything..

Comment: Okay follow this instruction exactly please so we can help you: post the output of `<%= t.path(:medium) %>` and `<%= t.url(:medium) %>`. We will get the PATH and relative URL of each photo, and we will make sure they exists at the given location. --- If it does not show anything, it's maybe because the @poster has no photos associated with it...

Comment: /photos/medium/missing.png As i understand it means that there are no pics..So, I've made something wrong in uploading photos.

Comment: Yes, I let you investigate about that since this depends on your data, good luck!

Comment: The point that I dont't understand, why when I load one image and when I have all forms for one image everything works fine and I see pics. But when I rewrite it for multiple uploading it's breaking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<% @poster.photos.each do |t| %>
<%= image_tag t.url(:medium) %>
<% end %>
```

Here was a problem. I should write

```
<%= image_tag t.photo.url(:medium) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined the style `:medium` in your `has_attached_file` declaration in the model ?

Try using it without the size :

```
<% @poster.photos.each do |t| %>
<%= image_tag t.url %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Yes, I did.. Everything works,when I'm making this for one file. But when trying to setup for multiple files it shows no images.