# Rails 6 Active storage sidekiq file upload background image on S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, file-upload, background, sidekiq

I am working on Rails 6 API and working on uploading multiple files using active storage on S3.

I need to upload large files and many files so I am thinking of using a background job.

As per my research active_storage use the background by default so no need to use the sidekiq, is that true?

If it's not using the background job then how to create the attachment in UploadAttachmentWorker?

**Attachment Controller**

```
def create
    @attachment_serializer = Array.new
    params[:data][:attachments].each do |attachment_params|
      params[:attachment_data] = attachment_params[1]
      @attachment = @account.attachments.create(attachments_params)
      @attachment_serializer << @attachment
  end
    if @attachment.save
      render json: AttachmentSerializer.new(@attachment_serializer, meta: {
        message: "Attachment Created Successfully"
      }).serializable_hash, status: :created
    else
      render json: {errors: format_activerecord_errors(@attachment.errors)},
        status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
  def attachments_params
    params.require(:attachment_data).permit :colour, :layout, :page_size, 
    :scale,:print_sides,:print_pages_from, :print_pages_to, :attachment
  end
```

**UploadAttachmentWorker**

```
class UploadAttachmentWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
    def perform()

    end
end
```

Please help me.

Comment: Working on a similar problem. A few ways have been listed out here (I myself am looking in particular to the method that involves threads)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162046/accelerate-s3-upload-with-paperclip/41866644#41866644

Comment: Cannot use sidekiq as we cannot pass file object to it. The two main factors that consume time are the size of file and even bigger the number of requests to S3. A 1 MB file will take less amount of time as compared to 5-6 few KB files because of the number of requests sent to cloud storage service (I have tested it via postman). First solution is to explore active storage's direct upload option. Second can be to, allow user to select any number of files on front end. Send the files one by one to the back end and show progress (1 on n files uploaded). Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

I am not literate on S3, but I did something similar with Cloundinary. I needed to upload PDF files, so I created a background jobs on my own. That being said, I might be wrong but I dont think that active_storage use the background by default.

You can have a look on my Job there: [BackgroundJob triggered multiple times on save ( Rails 5, Sidekiq)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64994252/backgroundjob-triggered-multiple-times-on-save-rails-5-sidekiq).