# BackgroundJob triggered multiple times on save ( Rails 5, Sidekiq)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jobs, sidekiq

I am handling the upload of PDFs' files on `Cloundinary` through a background jobs. I enqueue them from an `after_save` callback. The dilemna is that for one update my background job get triggered multiples times. To counter this flaw, I tried to  implement a method using `around_perform`, to ensure that my job would be triggered only one time.  But it actually did not work. I was wondering if any of you know how to handle those unwanted calls to the job

Here is my code

**My `after_save` callback**

The callback is placed on both my model Invoice and Quote.

```
Class Invoice
 after_save :upload_pdf

 def upload_pdf
   UploadPdfJob.perform_later(self.id,'invoice')

   new_notif_paid = Notification.create(user: self.user,
     category: "PDF",
     content: "Your PDF #{self.reference}
            is available ",
     element: "invoice",
     element_id: self.id)
 end
```

end

**My Job `UploadPDFJob`**

```
def perform(id, type)
   create_pdf_copy(id, type)
end


def create_pdf_copy(id, type)

  wicked = WickedPdf.new

  value = type == 'invoice'? Invoice.find(id) : Quote.find(id)
  template_path = type == 'invoice'? 'invoices/show': 'quotes/show.html.erb'
  file_type = type == 'invoice'? 'facture': 'devis'


  pdf_html = ApplicationController.render(
    locals: {
      current_user: value.user,
    },
    assigns: {
      "#{type}": value,
      format: 'pdf'
    },
    template: template_path,
    layout: 'pdf'
  )

  pdf_file = wicked.pdf_from_string(pdf_html,
    page_size: 'A4',
    orientation: "portrait",
    lowquality: true,
    zoom: 0.9,
    dpi: 75
  )

  tempfile = Tempfile.new("#{file_type}-#{value.id}.pdf")

  File.open(tempfile.path, 'wb') do |file|
    file << pdf_file
  end

  tempfile.close


  unless pdf_file.blank?
    value.photo.attach(io: File.open(tempfile.path), filename: "#{file_type}-#{value.id}.pdf")
  end
end
```

**My `around_perform`**

In this part, I put my instance in a variable named `element`.

The idea was that, if the `UploadPdfJob` job is enqueued more than once. The PDF will only be uploaded once. The first job will set `uploaded` to `true`, then the second job will exit after checking `done`

```
  around_perform do |job, block|
    id = job.arguments.first
    element = job.arguments.last == 'invoice'? Invoice.find(id) : Quote.find(id)
    element.with_lock do
      return if element.uploaded
      if block.call
        element.update(uploaded: true)
      else
        retry_job
      end
  end
```

Also, as I did not want to trigger the callback on the update, I tried this way. Using a variable called `start`, that does not rely on my retrieved instance

```
    around_perform do |job, block|
      id = job.arguments.first
      element = job.arguments.last == 'invoice'? Invoice.find(id) : Quote.find(id)
      start = false
      element.with_lock do
        return if start == true
        if block.call
          start = true
        else
          retry_job
        end
      end
    end
```

Comment: It likely is getting enqueued in different threads, so a thread local variable isn't good enough. It could also be being triggered by multiple saves happening. You may want to create a boolean on the database record or a related table like `pdf_generated`, and check that instead to determine whether it should run or not.

Comment: Can we see the after_save callback?

Comment: @Unixmonkey, that was exactly my first thought. Before using a "save" variable, I did a migration and used the attribute "uploaded" . I'm updating my post so you can see it clearly

Comment: @Schwern, I edited my post. You can see it now.

Comment: @DaviGo Is it `after_save :upload_pdf`? What class is the callback on? Where is the thing getting saved? The less we have to infer the easier it is to answer the question.

Comment: My guess is that the thing with the callback on it is being saved multiple times. You could check what's calling `upload_pdf` using [`caller`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-caller). `element.update(uploaded: true)` will trigger the callback.

Comment: @Schwern, Post edited. Hopefully now, it will be clearer.

Comment: @Schwern, yeah I came to the same conclusion on the `update`. Hence why I ended up turning to a variable completely independent of the created/updated instance. I did not know about the `#caller`, I will check this out. Thanks

Comment: @DaviGo Good luck. Note that Notification could take advantage of a [polymorphic association](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations).

Answer (score 0):

I had to roll up my sleeves, but I finally got the last word. I debugged with `binding.pry`,got to the very root of the problem and find out and updated every part of codes that were triggering my Job.

Also to further prevent any unwanted triggering, I added a customed guard callback stating which parameters saved should set the Job in motion.

```
Class Invoice

      after_save :upload_pdf, if: :should_upload?

      def should_upload?
        attributes = self.saved_changes
        %i[title client_id creation_date].any? {|val| attributes.key? val}
      end
    end
```